# Does This Geopolitical Power Balance Make it Look Like I am Promoting Colonialism?

Tags: warfare, politics, geopolitics, empire-building, galactic

The book series I'm working on can basically be summed up as a science-fantasy series that starts out leaning much more on the fantasy end of the spectrum (the first few books could best be described as a combination of Avatar: The Last Airbender, the Lord of the Rings, and Game of Thrones) but moves more and more towards the sci-fi end of the spectrum as it progresses until it looks like a cross between the Legend of Korra and Star Wars by the end.

The way this happens is that setting is essentially a brtual, 19-year-long war between the galaxy's biggest powers that industrializes the wider galaxy in what is practically the blink of an eye. Before the war, advanced technology was restricted to Ishga and the rest of the galaxy had early Renaissance-era technology, if that (except Caput Tatiium, which had spent a couple of decades industrializing by stealing Ishga technology, hiding out in its own remote corner of the galaxy, and brutally opressing the native population).

At the outbreak of war, the three main powers can basically be summed up as follows:

**Ishga**

-Based on the culture of Victorian-era London

-Ecumenopolis similar to Coruscant from Star Wars

-Technology so advanced it's basically indistinguishable from magic

-Had its industrial revolution about 200 years ago and has been led by an inbred royal family that bullied weaker planets for land and resources while greedily hoarding its own advancements ever since (however, a new king named Michael who is a supporting protagonist has ousted the old dynasty and wants to both democratize the planet and end and atone for the oppressive system of colonialism for which his forefathers are responsible. However, this is complicated by the fact that many of these colonies will be needed to win this galactic equivalent of WWII.)

-One main planet but has colonized several previously uninhabited worlds around it for use as farming colonies to feed itself and has bullied resources out of and taken land from worlds that are inhabited, to the detriment of those who live there.

-By far the most populous of the three main powers, being home to almost half the entire galaxy's population

**Aurea**

-Based mostly on Greco-Roman culture, but three of the outlying provinces are descended from various waves of settlers from elsewhere and are based mostly on Zulu, Mongolian, and Maori cultures respectively. In general, the military is based on the late Roman imperial system (but with Kommnenian-era Byzantine technology and weaponry), the government is essentially the Roman Republic with a non-term-limited US President called the "Dominus" in lieu of Consuls, and the Greek influence is mostly in matters of religion and culture that don't really affect this part of the worldbuilding.

-Least populous of the three main powers

-Aurea's current Dominus is our main protagonist, who is a close friend of King Michael of Ishga, and will spend the first few books both defending Aurea from Tate's minions and implementing an absolute ton of reforms to rapidly modernize the planet.

-Aurea is a single planet, but has extensive trade and diplomatic ties to those in its immediate area.

-Like all preindustrial worlds, Aurea conducts space travel with Startreaders, which I outlined in the context for a [previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/198446/how-would-limited-space-travel-change-late-medieval-early-renaissance-era-warfar).

-Those three outlying provinces I mentioned are composed of people groups completely separate from most Aureans, were conquered by the Aurean Government a few centuries back, and have a complicated relationship with their identity as Aureans, as well as with the Aurean Government.

**Caput Tatiium**

-Most of its population is composed of dozens of tribes based on various Native American and Inuit cultures that live in the rural areas. However, its government and military are mostly run by the detribalized urban population of mixed tribal heritage. This detribalized population only exists, however, because of a policy implemented a few decades back by Tate, which kicks rebellious tribes off their lands, forcibly disbands them, and scatters their people into various cities spread out across the planet.

-Led by Tate, a rogue mutant of Ishga heritage whose mutation gives him talent with magic that rivals the Gods' powers. Tate is the main antagonist of the series, and bases his worldview on the Ishgas' previous oppression of the galaxy. He sees the galaxy as so thoroughly ruined by Ishga colonialism that he wants to either conquer it all and rule it himself to fix the damage, or find and use a combination of long-lost ancient artifacts to summon the 3 primordial beings of the galaxy and have them create a new galaxy in his own image. His plan switches back and forth between the two depending on how well he is doing in the war (when he is winning and controls most of the galaxy, he is fine with the first plan, the second is his backup in case he starts losing). Tate rules Caput Tatiium as an absolute monarch.

-Second most populous of the three main powers

-Has spent the past three decades or so industrializing and modernizing its military with stolen Ishga technology acquired through Tate's allies in the galaxy's criminal underworld. However, most of these benefits have only reached the cities, and there is a MASSIVE wealth and technology gap between the cities and rural tribes.

-Uses its location on the far western edge of the galaxy (which has a reputation for being a barely inhabited backwater) to hide its massive industrialization projects and expansion through UNISYN

-Originally called Navayu before Tate's rule

**Various UNISYN Colonies**

-Before Tate's rise to power on Caput Tatiium, the vast majority of habitable planets in the galaxy were uninhabited. Seeing the golden opportunity, Tate, along with several prominent members of the galaxy's criminal underworld set up a massive pyramid scheme disguised as a legitimate company in which UNISYN sold people land on these worlds, and these people were rewarded for getting friends of theirs to buy in and get friends to join as well, and so on and so forth. The profits from this are basically what keep Caput Tatiium financially afloat.

-The majority of the war will be fought here

-Occupy the vast majority of the galaxy's area

-The vast majority of these worlds side with Tate and their inhabitants form the bulk of his military

-UNISYN Colonists are comrpised of all of the peoples of the galaxy, but those of Aurean, Caput Tatiian, and Ishga descent form a narrow majority of the population of these worlds

-Combined, the UNISYN colonies are second in population only to Ishga and will grow rapidly even as the war goes on

**Rest of the Galaxy**

-Composed of 10 Worlds: Planet Squid, Aztlan, Awal, Arturia, Ryu 97, Ryu 108, Atlantea, Bharatam, Vigam, and Rinascita

-All are generally at early Renaissance levels of technological, military, and societal development, but Rinascita, Bharatam and Ryu 97 are more advanced (Late Renaissance/Enlightenment), Ryu 108 and Planet Squid and Ryu 108 are less advanced (Iron Age), and Atlantea varies drastically by culture.

-Vigam, Aztlan, and Atlantea all have parts of their land under Ishga rule, Arturia has a history of oppressive Ishga rule in the past (although the current ruler has put this behind him and is a close friend of King Michael), and the rest all have some sort of unequal treaties with Ishga (kind of like the ones set up by European powers with China after the Opium Wars).

-Combined, these worlds are more populous than Aurea but less so than the UNISYN worlds. Many battles of the war will be fought here as well, as they are the cultural, historical, and magical heart of the galaxy and are home to most of the artifacts Tate needs for his ritual.

-These worlds will tepidly side with Ishga and Aurea at first, but many of their citizens have Tatian sympathies and all of these worlds change hands at least once during the war (Ryu 108 changes hands a whopping 4 times). Aztlan is the exception as Tate simply takes an artifact he needs, commits an almost total genocide on Aztlan's populace for reasons not relevant to this question, then leaves.

-The vast majority of both supporting protagonists and supporting antagonists are from these worlds.

**Finally, the actual question**

Now that we have that massive infodump out of the way, here is my question: Does having the reforming but still colonialist world of Ishga and the sort-of-colonialist world of Aurea portrayed (albeit with nuance) as MOSTLY "the good guys", while the (on paper) anti-colonialist (but incredibly hypocritical) world of Caput Tatiium portrayed (albeit with nuance and care to separate its rank and file people from Tate and his inner circle) portrayed as MOSTLY "the bad guys" make it look like I am promoting colonialism rather than being anti-colonialist?

Comment: @AlexP I have never heard of the Honorverse before and all resemblance to it is entirely coincidental. I'll be sure to give it a read sometime.

Comment: The first two books, [*On Basilisk Station*](https://www.baen.com/categories/free-library/on-basilisk-station.html) and [*The Honor of the Queen*](https://www.baen.com/categories/free-library/the-honor-of-the-queen.html) are freely available at the Baen Free Library. (Links go to the download pages.)

Comment: The word "colonialist" does not mean and has never meant "having colonies". Especially if the colonies were establish in previously uninhabited places. (The word for "having colonies" is "colonial". The word "colonialist" has a nebulous meaning, generally something close to "doing stuff I probably don't like to people I don't really care about".)

Comment: @AlexP yes, the Ishga farming colonies were built on previously uninhabited worlds but they also colonized and exploited the hell out of worlds that are inhabited (particularly Aztlan, Vigam, and Atlantea), and Aurea has those three provinces that are arguably colonies.

Comment: *"Exploited the hell out"* is an ideological position; what does it *actually* mean? How is "exploited the hell out" different from "developed"? Do the people of Vigam feel oppressed, or don't they? How many Ishga people actually moved to Vigam -- that is to say, did Ishga actually colonize Vigam? Is this colonialist oppression still on-going, or what is a phase of the past? Etc. etc.

Comment: @AlexP few Ishgas actually moved to Vigam, though they did take control of some land around the north pole where they took control of the planet's entire lazuliferrum mining industry (lazuliferrum is the ore the produces blue steel, an extremely valuable metal used in shipbuilding only found on that area of Vigam).

Comment: OK, and who was actually oppressed? As I see it, digging up dirt is hardly a crime. You can equally say the Ishgas developed the extractive industry on Vigam. If mcguffinite ore is so valuable, how come the Vigamians didn't develop the mines themselves and become rich and powerful? What I'm saying is that history is a rich and colorful tapestry full of wonderful details. Don't get hung up on the left-wing or right-wing or liberal or conservative "big picture": just tell the story the way you want to tell it. After all, in the "big picture" Achilles and Ulysses etc. were violent invaders...

Comment: @AlexP I said the Ishgas didn't develop it, they took control of mines that the Vigamians had already set up and sent the money and ore back to Ishga, devastating the Vigamian economy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is really a question for Writing SE, and not Worldbuilding. The question really isn't about worldbuilding, it's about a story and the reader's reaction to the setting.

Comment: To make a point: we're all here, enjoying this site and the fact of our lives, because of colonialism. Yes, it's politically correct (today) to hate colonialism, but that's really simplistic. It had its good (e.g., the culture of law, government, and civilization England brought to its territories) and its bad (the subjugation of native peoples) - but it happened. To dismiss it as simply evil is to dismiss ourselves as simply evil. I.E., the question shouldn't be "am I promoting colonialism?" The question should be "Am I presenting colonialism in a way that provokes thought and discussion?"

Answer (score 1):

- There is no law against promoting imperialism in fiction. (And beware that the word imperialism has [very different meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperialism,_the_Highest_Stage_of_Capitalism) depending on the place, on the time and on the political inclination of the speaker. It almost never means "cheering for an empire".)
- What is and what's not an empire is a complex question, and the name of a political structure is irrelevant.

  For example, the Russian Empire and the Union of Soviet Socialist Republics were basically the same thing, just with different management. The USSR was not less an empire than the Russian Empire.

  For another example, the Holy Roman Empire was not an empire in any reasonable sense of the word. It was a very loose confederation of sovereign states; even the European Union is a better approximation of an empire than the HRE.

  Finally, the People's Republic and the Celestial Empire are just two phases in the history of the same political structure.
- You may have heard of the Honorverse, a sprawling and wildly successful space opera created by David Weber. In that universe, the good guys are the Star Kingdom of Manticore, which later graduates to the Star Empire of Manticore. The original bad guys are the Republic of Heaven; then the massive Solarian League, which is a thinly veiled caricature of a combination of the European Union and the Celestial Empire, become the bad guys. (Won't tell you more, as it would spoil a major plot point.)

  Which means that having the good guys call themselves an empire is not inherently a bad thing.
- In real life, most Europeans consider than the Roman Empire (the real thing, not the fake HRE) was a good thing. If you look at it sideways, and squint your eyes, you could argue that the enture post-classical history of Europe is the history of repeated attempts to reconstitute the Roman Empire; with the current European Union being the Roman Empire 5.3, now with the Power of Subsidiarity.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I was referring more to "colonialism" than "imperialism" really and I will amend the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

I would say that *scientific* advance depends on *philosophical* advance.  People really need to have a kinder, fairer culture in order to reach and remain viable at a higher level of technology.  When writing that ancient cultures with vague ideas are able to sustain interstellar technology, you are proposing something that simply cannot function, and in so doing, could be counted as favoring misguided ways of thinking.

The most notable example commonly given is the invention of steam power during the Roman Empire.  Even though Heron had shown that this had immense potential, there was no way to recognize that beyond tricks with temple doors.  With slaves readily available, there was no great market in labor-saving technology, nor a coordinated effort to promote further research.

In our own time, we see similar issues with electronics.  Cameras are easily available and there were many places to post images; yet few stand up to say, for example, that women *will not* be discriminated against at their jobs due to "revenge porn".  Nor even that people wouldn't suffer economic punishments simply for favoring a political party.  (Indeed, we could have automated machinery taking over most jobs altogether, but we don't guarantee people another way to ensure their standards of living!)  The result is an internet on the decline, with declining quality of discourse, declining freedom, and increasingly less satisfaction even from such basic functions as search engines.   We had international trade, but without international environmental protection, or even coordinated efforts to track outbreaks of deadly disease, and now we see a retreat from that as well.

Now extend this to interstellar technology.  Imagine what happens when people can fly a massive ship at a fraction of the speed of light and aim it at the capital of a planet.  Imagine what a galaxy is like when villains can abscond with a slave ship to any planet, and begin breeding themselves an empire of biologically and mechanically modified servants to attack their neighbors.

A culture at the level of technology you suggest would need to be one vastly more advanced, socially, than any that the world has ever known.  This is a time to plan a utopia, or else to write a recipe for failure.

Comment: *"With slaves readily available":* Pet peeve. The vast, overwhelming majority of the workforce in the Roman Empire were free people, not slaves. Slaves were most usually *very expensive*, except for a handful of very short time exceptions. The high point of slave labor was roughly the late 2nd - early 1st century **B**CE agriculture in some limited areas, mostly Sicily. Moreover, the Romans had this habit of manumitting slaves born in-house, with the effect that once the empire stopped growing in the 1st century CE, the number of slaves fell; by the 3rd century there were really few of them.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_ancient_Rome) gives a figure of 30-40% ... and, being slaves, I imagine they did a considerably higher percentage of the *work*.

Comment: Yes, as I said, late 2nd century BCE to early 1st century BCE was the high point; and not even then were slaves a majority of rural workers.  (Most slaves worked in agriculture, constituing what the Romans called *familia rustica*.) A few lines down you find that by the 4th century they dwindled to 10% of the population. (P.S. Slaves are very inefficient workers. I wouldn't begin to guess why you believe that slaves work harder than employees. The Romans had a clever way to work around this: they allowed slaves to go find work for hire in order to get money to buy themselves free.)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the actual question being asked. All this answer is stating is that any interstellar political system that isn't a borderline utopia and radically different from any political system tried prior in human history is doomed to failure, and doesn't address the OP's actual concern of whether their particular setting is supporting colonialism. Indeed, the OP's particular setting or colonialism isn't even mentioned in this answer.